# Rank each row in a table and group the rows for duplicates without resetting the rank for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, transactions

I have the below table created with me:

```
dishname         rating rank
Fish Fry          5.0    1
Tandoori Chicken  4.8    2
Tandoori Chicken  4.6    3
Paneer Tikka      4.5    4
Baby Corn         4.2    5
Fish Fry          4.1    6
Paneer Tikka      3.9    7
Baby Corn         3.1    8
Fish Fry          2.9    9
Paneer Tikka      2.3   10
```

*Assume that each dish is from a different restaurant

Code used:

```
Select dishname,
       rating, 
       Row_Number() Over(Order By rating desc) as Rank 
From DISH
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
dishname          rating  rank
Fish Fry           5.0     1
Fish Fry           4.1     6
Fish Fry           2.9     9
Tandoori Chicken   4.8     2
Tandoori Chicken   4.6     3
Paneer Tikka       4.5     4
Paneer Tikka       3.9     7
Paneer Tikka       2.3     10
Baby Corn          4.2     5
Baby Corn          3.1     8
```

I want the dish with rank 1 to be on the top of the table followed by the same dish (with different rank as shown above). Once this is done, then the criteria to select the next dish should be to check for the next rank (for a different dish). The first dish of each group is selected based on the Rank column and within the group the dishes should be order by rank.

CURRENT TABLE WITH FOUR DISHES
[Please click for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3QAG.jpg)

WHAT I AM EXPECTING
[Please click for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sarQ.jpg)

Comment: Please dont use pictures. Use tables instead

Comment: Sorry...new to Stack Overflow...I ll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @DISH TABLE ( dishname varchar(20), rating decimal(18,2) )
INSERT INTO @DISH VALUES 
('Fish Fry'          ,5.0),
('Tandoori Chicken'  ,4.8),
('Tandoori Chicken'  ,4.6),
('Paneer Tikka'      ,4.5),
('Baby Corn'         ,4.2),
('Fish Fry'          ,4.1),
('Paneer Tikka'      ,3.9),
('Baby Corn'         ,3.1),
('Fish Fry'          ,2.9),
('Fish Fry'          ,1.9),
('Paneer Tikka'      ,2.3),
('Tandoori Chicken'  ,3.2),
('Tandoori Chicken'  ,1.7),
('Paneer Tikka'      ,2.0)



SELECT dishname, rating, Rank  
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        Row_Number() Over(Order By SubRank, rating desc) as Rank,
        MAX(rating) OVER(PARTITION BY SubRank, dishname) as FirstOrdeR
    FROM (
        Select dishname,
               rating, 
               ((Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY dishname ORDER BY rating desc))-1) / 3 as SubRank 
        From @DISH
    ) AS T 
) AS X
ORDER BY SubRank, FirstOrder DESC, Rank
```

Result:

```
dishname             rating                                  Rank
-------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------
Fish Fry             5.00                                    1
Fish Fry             4.10                                    6
Fish Fry             2.90                                    10
Tandoori Chicken     4.80                                    2
Tandoori Chicken     4.60                                    3
Tandoori Chicken     3.20                                    8
Paneer Tikka         4.50                                    4
Paneer Tikka         3.90                                    7
Paneer Tikka         2.30                                    11
Baby Corn            4.20                                    5
Baby Corn            3.10                                    9
Paneer Tikka         2.00                                    12
Fish Fry             1.90                                    13
Tandoori Chicken     1.70                                    14
```

Comment: Its working like a dream...but there is still one thing that I forgot to mention in the original query...if the same dish is listed more than 3 times I want to pick only the top three for that dish...for example...if we had another entry for Fish Tikka with 1.5 rating that should not be displayed with the first three Fish Tikka...but should display later in the list based on the rank....

Comment: Hi Sarslan...the update shows the first three dishes of each group which is as expected but it omits the fourth dish of a group from the table and doesw not list it at all...what I want is if a dish for e.g. Fish Fry has a fourth row with rating 2.5, then it should not be listed in the first three Fish Tikka list but should be listed after the last Baby Corn dish. Similarly for other dishes if they have a fourth dish in their group

Comment: I am not able to copy tables in here or in my original question...otherwise I would have shown what I want.

Comment: I have added photos of tables showing dishes with 4 in each group and how I am expecting them to be listed....please have a look and help me out...

Comment: Thanks a ton sarslan...it works like a charm... :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

I use CROSS APPLY to select the minimum rank, and use that as an sortorder.

```
       declare @myt table (dishname  nvarchar(50),       rating float, rank int)
insert into @myt
values 

('Fish Fry'          ,5.0  , 1),
('Tandoori Chicken'  ,4.8  , 2),
('Tandoori Chicken'  ,4.6  , 3),
('Paneer Tikka'      ,4.5  , 4),
('Baby Corn'         ,4.2  , 5),
('Fish Fry'          ,4.1  , 6),
('Paneer Tikka'      ,3.9  , 7),
('Baby Corn'         ,3.1  , 8),
('Fish Fry'          ,2.9  , 9),
('Paneer Tikka'      ,2.3  ,10)



select z.Dishname,rating,[rank] from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by dishname order by [Rank] asc,rating desc) rn from (

Select dishname,
       rating, 
       Row_Number() Over(Order By rating desc) as [Rank] 
From @myt
)X 
) z

cross apply (select  MIN(rank) as sortorder,dishname from @myt s

where s.dishname = z.dishname group by dishname) f

order by sortorder,rn
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Hi plaidDK...thanks for the code...but the column 'Rank' was created by my code: "Select dishname,rating, Row_Number() Over(Order By rating desc) as rank From DISH".............I am not able to collate my code with yours...its saying Rank as invalid

Comment: Yes and ? Then just include that in the inner select statement

Comment: @SridharN because i called it ranks. Just edit the name to what your name is

Comment: @SridharN i now changed the code to use your  rank code. Now it says rank.

Answer (score 0):

Process here is to be able to join between the rankings and the best ranking for each dish. Then can sort on the best ranking first.

```
with ranking as (
    select dishname, rating, rank() over(order by rating) as dr
    from Dish
), topRanking as (
    select dishname, max(dr) as maxRank
    from ranking
    group by dishname
)
select r.dishname, r.rating
from ranking r
    inner join topRanking tr on tr.dishname = r.dishname
order by maxRank desc, rating desc
```

Comment: Hi Richard...The code is working...but the ranks (in this case 'dr') are in reverse...I mean the highest rating dish has rank as 10 and the lowest rated dish has rank as 1....can we reverse that??...also if we have more than 3 dishes with same name all of them are being listed now....can we restrict that to 3 dishes of same name???...really looking forward for ur help

Comment: @SridharN: that comment makes no sense.

Comment: sorry for the first comment...was trying to insert a table...dint work

Comment: To reverse the order of `dr` reverse the sort for the `rank` and switch from `max(dr)` on second CTE to `min(dr)`. Depending on exact requirements `dense_rank()` might be better than `rank()`. (There is limited formatting and space in comments: usually better to edit the question or answer.)

Answer (score 0):

A single-CTE based approach, though possibly *a little less* efficient than other answers:

```
--DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(dishname varchar(10), rating decimal(2,1))
--INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('Fish', 5.0), ('Chicken', 4.8), ('Chicken', 4.6), ('Tikka', 4.5), ('Corn', 4.2), ('Fish', 4.1), ('Tikka', 3.9), ('Corn', 3.1), ('Fish', 2.9), ('Tikka', 2.3) /* extra records */ , ('Fish', 1.9), ('Chicken', 3.2), ('Chicken', 1.7), ('Tikka', 2.0)

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        *
      , [Rank] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY rating DESC)
      , [Group] = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dishname ORDER BY rating DESC) - 1) / 3
    FROM @TABLE
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE AS A
ORDER BY [Group], (SELECT MIN([Rank]) FROM CTE AS B WHERE A.dishname = B.dishname AND A.[Group] = B.[Group]), rating DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select dishname,rating, Row_Number() Over as Rank From DISH where order by dishname('Fish Fry','Tandoori Chicken','Panner Tikka','Baby Corn') order by Over DESC;
```

This is specific to MySQl

Comment: Hi...I forgot to mention that I am using this table as an example... In reality I will have 100s of dishes..